# Роутинг между двумя интерфейсами

Tags: windows, маршрутизация, openvpn

Есть хост №1. Платформа Windows.
Локальная сеть lan0 10.100.10.0/24
Виртуальный tun0 172.10.10.0/24
Крутится OpenVPN сервер.

Подключаюсь по ovpn к хосту. Сеть 172.10.10.0 вижу и пингую.
Сеть lan0 не вижу.

Как настроить роутинг между tun0 и lan0?

На хосте пробовал добавлять статические маршруты, указывал gateway. Результата не дало.

В конфе клиента ovpn пробовал указывать сети вручную, но результата не получил.

Upd. Пробовал указать на сервере openvpn опцию server-bridge, адреса раздаются, но сеть все равно не пингуется. Только клиенты видят себя.

Comment: А хостам из сети 10.100.10.0/24 кто-нибудь рассказал о том как им отправлять ответные пакеты в сеть 172.10.10.0/24?

Comment: Да, я прописал маршруты

Comment: Я с хоста 10.100.10.1 пингую 172.10.10.1 и обратно. Но если подключаю клиента, то могу пинговать только 172.10.10.1

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос можно закрыть. 
Столкнулся с интересным поведением клиента OpenVPN на андройде. При одинаковом конфиге работает по-разному.

Попробовал на Windows с тем же клиентским конфигом — всё работает как должно, и сети видно, и туннулирование работает.
Буду ковырять ведро.